# Can I get the browsersync proxy to not update a particular URL?

Tags: wordpress, proxy, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

## Details:

I create virtual hosts for development like `http://project.client.dev` and then use browsersync for live reloading and whatnot, which creates a proxy at `http://localhost:3000`. This causes all URLs on the page to be written to `http://localhost:3000`, which in 99% of cases is exactly what I want, but sometimes I want to link to that original `http://project.client.dev` path instead.

### Question:

Is it possible to have browsersync *not* update just particular URLs? Like, add a class of `do-not-update` or something and have those stay `http://project.client.dev` instead of being updated to `http://localhost:3000`?

### Use Case:

I build WordPress websites. When I'm clicking around the site's front-end I want those `http://localhost:300` addresses so live reloading occurs. On the back-end however, I don't want those paths ending up in the database or, worse yet, browsersync reloading my admin screens while I'm editing content. Typically I just open one tab on the front-end and one on the back-end using the respective domains, but I'd like to add an in-development link to the footer that says "edit page ID 123" and opens the current front-end page up on the back-end for editing; problem is, it opens the `http://localhost:3000` version of the back-end and I need to manually update the URL every time (provided I remember to do so).

Answer (score 0):

I think is it not possible at this moment to exclude some URLs. But have a look at the documentation : https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options

Comment: I've looked through that and haven't found anything. rewriteRules looked promising but unfortunately it only allows editing the path following the domain, and I need to change the domain.

Comment: Ok, tell everyone that is probably possible using this way :-)

Answer (score 0):

As [Paul wrote it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46609253/1863761), Browsersync does not seem to have an option to achieve that for now.

As a workaround, may be you can use a JS snippet to *roll back* Browsersync URL changes on URL matching some masks.

Example (for WP admin links) :

```
const schemeHost    = 'https://yourhost';

document.querySelectorAll( '[href*="//localhost"][href*="wp-admin"]' ).forEach( link => {
  link.setAttribute( 'href', link.getAttribute( 'href' ).replace( /^(?:http:|https:)?\/\/localhost(?::[0-9]+)?/g, schemeHost ) )
} );
```

You may adapt this snippet for other places you need it such as image src or whatever